# Moving transitive dependency from implementation to testImplementation

Tags: gradle

I have few dependencies, that have the same transitive dependency for tests, resulting in test dependencies ending up in my 'implementation'.

Can I somehow smoothly redirect said dependency to 'testImplementation' or do I have to perform something like:

```
implementation(A){exclude T}
implementation(B){exclude T}
implementation(C){exclude T}
testImplementation(T)
```

Comment: Is `T` a required dependency for `A-C` to function correctly? In other words, is `T` part of the API for `A-C`? If not, then dependencies `A-C` should not be declaring `T` as an `api` dependency and instead declare it as `compileOnly` or use [feature variants](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html) to avoid adding unnecessary dependencies to consumers

Comment: I do not have a control over A-C and T is not required.

Comment: You should be able to exclude T at the configuration level (i.e. for all 'implementation') so you don't need to exclude it for each individual implementation dependency that pulls it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something a bit better would be:

```
configurations {
  implementation {
    exclude(T)
  }
}
testImplementation(T)
```

Then you won't need to explicitly exclude `T` for each `implementation` dependency that might pull it in.